# Bootstrap - Left Align Link in a Row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a Bootrap 4.6 app. In this app, I need to display a "back" button in a row. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-25 pb-0" style="background-image:url(/images/backgrounds/bg-1.jpg);">
  <div class="row py-4 my-2" style="max-width:1500px;">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="text-white" href="/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left mr-2"></i>GO BACK</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this time, when my page renders, the "go back" button is horizontally aligned in the middle of the page, like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
|                    < GO BACK                     |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

However, in reality, I need it to look like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
|          < GO BACK                               |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I believe the `max-width:1500px` on the row element is throwing things off. Yet, I'm unsure. How can I left align content in a centered container if that makes sense?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied and pasted the code you had written and it appeared left aligned. It is likely nested within another component that has the class `text-center`.
In any case you can specify the class `text-left` inside your `div` tag, before the `a` tag.
Finally, to get the desired effect, just add a `margin-left` to your button. You can use the `ml-5` bootstrap class as in the following example.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-25 pb-0 bg-dark" style="background-image:url(/images/backgrounds/bg-1.jpg);">
  <div class="row py-4 my-2 text-center" style="max-width:1500px;">
    <div class="col text-left">
      <a class="text-white ml-5 text-left bg-danger" href="/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left mr-2"></i>GO BACK</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```